# Remove whitespace between uneven height divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small gallery with pictures that have the same width but different height. My problem is that as soon as the second row of images comes up it begins only at the bottom of the highest div from the previous 'row' - sorry for my paint skills :D

This is how my divs look like:

```
<div><img src=""></div>
<div><img src=""></div>
<div><img src=""></div>
<div><img src=""></div>
<div><img src=""></div>
<div><img src=""></div>
<div><img src=""></div>
<div><img src=""></div>
```

[image: grid elements]

How do i make those blank spaces to disappearn so i can have a smooth layout?(i want to keep the different heights look tho :( )

Comment: consider using masonry layout

Comment: As @TemaniAfif Said, Take a look at [MasonryJs](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Can you post your current CSS as well? Better yet, create a working code snippet so we can see exactly what is happening with your code and you can put your paint skills to rest ;)

Comment: i've got so mad at it that i've deleted it X_X

Comment: I urge you to recreate it

Comment: Perhaps rather than using rows you could use columns?

Comment: Use isotope - https://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 1):

Hei guys, first of all thank you all for taking some of your time to try and help me! :D

I think i found a pretty easy solution that doesn't involve js.

This is the CSS:

```
.gallery{
    max-width: 1150px;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 75px auto 100px;
}

.gallery ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -moz-columns: 3;
    columns: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px;
    column-fill: balance;
}

.gallery ul li{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.gallery ul li:nth-child(1){
   margin-top: 0;
}

.gallery ul li img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 860px){
    .gallery{
        max-width: 700px;
    }
    .gallery ul{
        -webkit-columns: 2;
        -moz-columns: 2;
        columns: 2;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px){
    .gallery ul{
        -webkit-columns: 1;
        -moz-columns: 1;
        columns: 1;
    }
}
```

And this is the HTML file(i'm using PHP to fetch data from a database since i stored my thumbs and images in a database):

```
<div class="gallery">
    <?php if(!empty($images)): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
               <li><img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>"></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>No images yet.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Notice that the first child of that unordered list has a margin top set to zero, you have to take care on that cause otherways it'll push either the second column or the third(in my case there are only 3 columns) those 10px from the top and therefore you'll lose that nice top alignment.

For more about multicomlumns you can visit [W3 multicol layout module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-multicol-1/)